# 2 monitors mirrored - want extended and correct resolution

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 15.10

Ok I've always used ati catalyst drivers however given that this is broken in kernel 4.2 and I see people always saying to just use the open source ones I did just that in my Ubuntu 15.10 install.

When I have the proprietary drivers installed and use kernel 4.1 to boot everything works. Screen 1 1920x1080 and screen 2 1440x900 and displays in extended mode as intended.

However when I now use the open source I have a mess.

Only one monitor display actually seems to be detected as in Displays under settings only one shows up. It's set a screen resolution of 1280x1024. Both displays are displaying content but it is exactly the same content. I wouldn't call it mirroring as such given that it doesn't recognise both displays.
xrandr shows this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 400, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      0.00* 
   1152x864       0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00  
   720x400        0.00
```

Under the proprietary drivers I had my 1920x1080 showing as Screen 0 and my 1440x900 showing as CRT1 in xrandr with all the different resolutions.

Can anyone help me sort this mess out?

Edit for more info:

My graphics card is Radeon HD 6850 and it's connected to a 32 inch Samsung TV through HDMI and and 19" VGA monitor connected via a VGA to DVI converter to DVI on the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's some news I hate to break to you: You'll have to stay on versions that can work with the Catalyst drivers, because from my past experience, older AMD cards like to make issues with the open source drivers.

Comment: LOL - they can't cope with the old or the new - what are they good for :D I'll just continue to boot kernel 4.1 in 15.10 until 4.2 drivers are released by AMD.

Comment: @EamonnDoyle Good idea